# Bourne Shell trying to cd into a $variable path?

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

I'm trying something very simple:

```
MYPATH=/path/I/want/to/go/to/
...
cd $MYPATH
```

No good. I've tried various permutations of quotes around things and it doesn't seem to help. So how is this done?

Comment: Is that an existing directory that you can read ?

Comment: Oh wait nvm, it did seem to work because when I echo'd `ls` it gave me the contents of that dir. I was just really thrown off because the actual terminal seemed to cd "back" to where the script was called from. (This in response to the deleted answer, put it back and I'll accept)

Comment: I've done it, trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that an existing directory that you can read ?

You may want to add this before the `cd` if the directory may not exist :

```
 mkdir -p $MYPATH
```

Comment: Yeah the folder did exist, I just got confused when after the .sh script finished running it brought me back to the same directory I started in, so I thought nothing happened.

Comment: OK... now I understand your last comment.

Comment: As I didn't really answered your problem, you may make an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

your shellscript runs in a separate shell, the shell from which you started is generally unaffected by the scripts actions (with the exception of things that are meant to affect it, such as filesystem changes).  if you want to have a piece of code "just like" a script but affecting the invoking shell, use a function with a curly-braces body:

*~/.mystuff/dostuff.func*:

```
dostuff()
{
  cd /some/where
}
```

your *.profile*:

```
. ~/.mystuff/dostuff.func
```

start a login shell, and do

```
dostuff
```

you should be in `/some/where` (if it exists on your computer).